# Can't add image to text on Bootstrap button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and sometimes it is hard to overwrite it.

I want to add some picture to my button, near text. So I added background-image, but it doesn't apply.

Here is css for my button:

```
 .submit .report{
font-size: 18px;
text-shadow: none;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 5px;
width:300px;
color:white;
filter:alpha(opacity=100);
background: #628d28;
background-image:url('../images/picture.png') no-repeat;
}
```

BUT Firebug say, that my element has next CSS:

```
  .submit .report{
font-size: 18px;
text-shadow: none;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 5px;
width:300px;
color:white;
filter:alpha(opacity=100);
background-image: none repeat color(98,141,40);

}
```

Why I can't add background image ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define wrong **background** properties. Write like this:

```
.submit .report{
background-color: #628d28;
background-image:url('../images/picture.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

**OR**

```
.submit .report{
    background: #628d28 url('../images/picture.png') no-repeat;
 }
```

Comment: Hi.. If I write no-repeat I cant see the image, and if I dont write no-repeat then I see multiple image as background.

Comment: .icon-flight {
 background-image: url('../img/flight.png') ;
 background-position:center center;
}